# How to replace the place holder with the dynamic text in the HTML Email template using string.Format()

Tags: c#, html

I have one email template containing CSS (NOT a Inline CSS), and I want replace the body text dynamically. I have tried below approach to not get the invalid content error.

```
string htmlBody = builder.HtmlBody.Replace("{", "{{").Replace("}", "}}");
string body = string.Format(htmlBody, dynamictext);

 using (var client = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient("AccessKey", "SecretAccess",RegionEndpoint.USWest2))
            {
                var response = new SendEmailResponse();
                var emailRequest = new SendEmailRequest()
                {
                    Source = "from email ID",
                    Destination = new Destination(),
                    Message = new Amazon.SimpleEmail.Model.Message()
                };

                emailRequest.Destination.ToAddresses.Add(EmailId);
                emailRequest.Message.Subject = new Content("subject");
                emailRequest.Message.Body = new Amazon.SimpleEmail.Model.Body(new Content(body));

                try
                {
                    var x = await client.SendEmailAsync(emailRequest);
                    return 1;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                    return 0;
                }
            }
```

but the dynamic content is not getting replaced in the HTML template, its showing as {{{0}}}, instated of replacing the place holder value at {0}.

below is the example Body Content
Hello FirstName LastName (this field I want to replace to I had placed the {0} place holder),

Congratulations!!
Your account is successfully created!

To access your account, please visit {1} or click login from the payzli.com home page.

could anyone please let me know where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Have you read the tag descriptions for `[asp.net]` and `[asp.net-core]`? Especially the last part on `[asp.net]`: _"Do NOT use this tag for questions about ASP.NET Core - use [asp.net-core] instead."_ (source: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/asp.net/info)

Comment: If the placeholder in `htmlBody` isn't the literal string `"{0}"`, then `string.Format` won't work with it.

Comment: Maybe you understand when you do this: `string htmlBody = builder.HtmlBody.Replace("{", "{{").Replace("}", "}}").Replace("{{0}}", "{0}");`

Comment: @Silvermind  Thank you , I tried  double replacing it and worked for me .

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you want to do; but you can do something like this:

```
string htmlBody = "a:link {{ color:  {0}; }}";
string dyn = "pink";
string Body = string.Format(htmlBody, dyn);
Console.WriteLine(Body);
```

Output will be

```
a:link { color:  pink; }
```